# connecting ac and dc sources together in series

Tags: power-electronics

I want a small signal ac voltage riding over a dc voltage, but when I connect my signal generator in series with the DC power source,then the two sources get coupled.I mean if i try to change the ac amplitude the DC amplitude changes too and vice versa.So  any solutions for this problem?/

Comment: ["Modulation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=modulator+circuit)

Answer (score 2):

You should've provided us with more details. For instance, knowing what components you're using for DC and AC sources could lead to a specific answer.

In general, his behavior may be caused by either of the following:

1. The current through your circuit exceeding the limit of one of the sources (usually AC), in which case strange behavior can be seen (the exact behavior depends on the components).
2. Your AC source is "grounded" - one of its outputs (usually the "-") must be connected to the ground of the circuit (I'm assuming here that the ground of your circuit is defined by the "-" output of the DC source).

Since I believe that your issue is #2 above (and because it is trivial to check for #1), you have few options (the ones I can think of):

1. The answer by @Jim Dearden is the most robust way to proceed with (maybe not the exact configuration, but the employment of op-amp)
2. However, there might be shorter solution: check your DC power supply spec. If its outputs may be floating, then you can switch places between AC and DC supplies in you circuit. This will allow you to satisfy "grounded" constraint of your AC supply, while keeping both supplies in series.

Answer (score 1):

Use an op amp to combine the signals.

[image]

Virually any op amp should work (e.g tl071, 741)

The op amp is set up with with a gain of 1.

The AC signal is fed (through a decoupling capacitor) to the inverting input.

The DC signal is fed through a resistor to the non inverting input.

The two signals will be added together (AC will suffer a 180 degree phase shift) and appear as a mixed signal at the output.

Take care not to set the DC voltage input greater than the supply voltage of the op amp.

As you will need to supply the op amp with a dc voltage you could tap into this for your DC value.

[image]

Comment: for the second configuration, can any DC power supply be employed, or it must have floating outputs?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov I've put up a very generic circuit that uses a split voltage supply for the op amp as I wasn't certain exactly what the set up was in the original question. Normally there would be one terminal designated as ground (0V) with other voltages relative to it. However you could implement the power to the op amp with just a couple of batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal generator will likely have two things that make it difficult to directly connect in series with the DC source: -

- It may not like its 0V (gnd) point raising more than a couple of volts above ground if at all.
- The output impedance is not going to be zero. A lot of sig gens have a 50 ohm output impedance and the dc current will have to flow through the output of the signal generator and potentially through 50 ohms (or 600 ohms in some cases) - any dc load you place on the pair in series will result in poor dc regulation and reduced dc.

The simplest option is to use an output transformer on the signal generator: -

[image]

If your signal source is audio choose an audio transformer like this: -

[image]

Notice the red circle - it's telling you that the DC resistance of the secondary is less than 1 ohm and this means the DC capabilites of the pair in series won't be much affected by light to moderate DC loads. Don't try forcing an amp through it though because you'll saturate the core and affect the amplitude of the AC signal and cause distortion and possibly ultimately damage the transformer. There are audio transformers that can be found that are good for 100mA flowing in the output winding - these were used in telephone modems.

Note that the audio transformer doesn't need to have windings that are tapped (like the one in the picture). I quickly found this to demonstrate a suitable candidate. 1:1 or 2:1 transformers with single primary and secondary windings are the basic type to use. Split/tapped windings give you more options that you probably don't require but could be useful on other things.

If your ac source is in the rf regions you'll need an appropriate transformer suitable for those frequencies.